# Meaning of some syntax used in a monad tutorial

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

While I was reading [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) tutorial on monads, found the following expression.

> data M a = Raise Exception | Return a
>
> type Exception = String

It says that a is used as a type variable and a range of values in Raise Exception and Return a, but I don't understand the use (or the meaning) of M here. If M is a data type Why is it used like M a ?

Comment: I assume this is Haskell code; if so, you might consider re-tagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M` is the name of the type constructor being defined, `a` is a type parameter to this constructor. To use the data type later you will have to give the constructor `M` and supply a type argument for `a`, e.g. `M Int`.

Comment: M is not a Data Type, It is a Data Type Constructor to be precise.

Answer (score 5):

You need to distinguish between Value Constructors and Type Constructors.

`M` is not a Data Type, it is a Data Type Constructor. So to construct a datatype of Type `M a` you give the Type constructor `M`, a data type of Type `a` to get data type of type `M a`.
For example a data type `M Int` or `M String`.

On the other hand `Raise` and `Return` are value constructors here. So to get a value of type say `M Int` you feed the value constructor `Return` a value of Type `Int`, like `Return 2`.

There is a nice theory behind this. You can read more about value and type constructors [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor).